# System IO Exception : the process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process c#

Tags: c#, .net

I have seen several post  for this problem .I have implemented all suggestion like using flush() , close() method on streamwriter and connection Object,use GC.Collect() to force cleanup,, use using{} to autodispose

I am Doing Simple Get Operation from DB and write to text file ..here is my Code

```
public void WriteToFile(string ProductName)
{
    //Already Got Data from DB and stored in "ProductName" 

   //saving in File
    if (!File.Exists(path11))
    {
        File.Create(path11);
        StreamWriter tw = new StreamWriter(path11);
        tw.WriteLine(ProductName+"@"+DateTime.Now.ToString());

        tw.Flush();
        tw.Close();
    }
    else if (File.Exists(path11))
    {
        StreamWriter tw = new StreamWriter(path11, true);
        tw.WriteLine(ProductName + "@" + DateTime.Now.ToString());

        tw.Flush();
        tw.Close();
    }

    GC.Collect();
}
```

Another suggestion I Got is to lock the object ..But I cannot implement it ..
Any suggestion would be Helpful

Comment: Delete the call to `File.Create`; `new StreamWriter(path11)` will create the file if it doesn't exist.

Comment: yes I did . i Updated the post ...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`File.Create` creates the file and returns an open stream. You don't really need all that logic. Just use `new StreamWriter(path11, true)` which will create the file if it doesn't exist and append to it if it does. Also `using` is helpful:

```
public void WriteToFile(string ProductName)
{
    //Get Data from DB and stored in "ProductName"
    using (var tw = new StreamWriter(path11, true))
    {
        tw.WriteLine(ProductName+"@"+DateTime.Now.ToString());
    }
}
```

Comment: @user3734952: you should accept the answer which helped you to solve the issue by checking tick mark beside the answer.

Comment: I can accept only after 6 minutes ..I was waiting for that

Answer (score 2):

`FileCreate` returns a stream which you should use to instantiate `StreamWriter`:

```
var file = File.Create(path11);
StreamWriter tw = new StreamWriter(file);
```

And you should use `using` blocks to make sure your stream and file is closed when you're finished writing.