# C# writing to a text file issue

Tags: c#

I have a simple enough class that is used to log text to a .txt file im getting the the issue that if the text file does not exist I will get an exception at the point shown in the code. Then the text file appears in the folder after the program has crashed. If I run the program while the log.txt file exists it works perfect.

The code:

```
class logger
{
        public string source;
        //public logger()
        //{

        //}
        public logger(string source)
        {
            CheckExists(source);
            this.source = source + "log.txt";
        }
        private void CheckExists(string source)
        {
            if (!File.Exists(source + "log.txt"))
            {
                File.Create(source + "log.txt");
            }
        }
        public void WriteToLog(string output)
        {
            try
            {
                using (StreamWriter sw = File.AppendText(this.source))
                {
                    sw.WriteLine(output);
                    sw.Close();
                }
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {

                //point at which the code breaks;
            }

        }
}
```

Comment: And what is the exception message?

Comment: `File.Create` creates *and* opens the file

Comment: possible duplicate of [System IO Exception : the process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process c#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24226421/system-io-exception-the-process-cannot-access-the-file-because-it-is-being-use)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`File.Create()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d62kzs03%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) leaves the file open until the garbage collector runs, since it returns a `FileStream` that you are supposed to close. Because it is left open, you are probably getting a sharing violation when you subsequently try to open it.

A better way to create the file is like this:

```
File.WriteAllText(source + "log.txt", "");
```

which will close the file afterwards.

Answer (score 5):

Why don't you just use [File.AppendAllText](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143356(v=vs.110).aspx)

```
File.AppendAllText(this.source, output);
```

Comment: That would indeed probably be better!

Comment: Hi aharon, I've formatted your answer a little and added supporting information, you may want to click the edit button to see how this has been done for future answers (+1 btw)

Comment: +1 mentioning AppendAllText `Opens a file, appends the specified string to the file, and then closes the file. If the file does not exist, this method creates a file..`

Answer (score 1):

Don't forget to close.

```
File.Create(source + "log.txt").Close();
```